# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found:

Tags: ios4, dyld

When I try to run my project in iOS 4.3 Simulator, it throws me following exception:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect
  Referenced from: /Users/macintosh/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/FCBB8196-9F46-4F4E-BFB3-C28D0AAEC74F/Tick.app/Tick
  Expected in: /Users/macintosh/Desktop/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics

dyld: Symbol not found: _CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect
  Referenced from: /Users/macintosh/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/FCBB8196-9F46-4F4E-BFB3-C28D0AAEC74F/Tick.app/Tick
  Expected in: /Users/macintosh/Desktop/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
```

I have set target to ios 4.3. My project runs fine on ios 5 and 6. I think some library is missing or is not supported in old version. What should I do to resolve this problem? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect` is not available on iOS 4.3. It was new in iOS 5.0.